# How many pixels font-size have for elements?

Tags: css

If font size is 16px, does that mean it is 16px tall and 16 px wide?

I am trying to make a banner and the banner needs to be 40 px tall.  The font in the banner is 16 px in font size, so if I give the font a top and bottom margin of 12 px then the banner will be 40 px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This image should help... Read more about it at http://thenewcode.com/606/Molten-Leading-Exploring-The-CSS-Relationship-Between-Font-Size-LineHeight-and-Margin

Answer (score 1):

[Pixel is Not square !! Pixel is not Square](http://alvyray.com/Memos/CG/Microsoft/6_pixel.pdf)

There is great reading at  [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html) on this

i would like to quote some point here from the given link

> On a laser printer, 1cm should be exactly 1 centimeter. But on
>   low-resolution devices, such as computer screens, CSS doesn't require
>   that. And indeed, the result tends to be different from one device to
>   another and from one CSS implementation to another. It's better to
>   reserve these units for high-resolution devices and in particular for
>   printed output. On computer screens and handheld devices, you'll
>   probably not get what you expect.

***Px depends on Device***

> The px unit is the magic unit of CSS. It is not related to the current
>   font and usually not relatated to physical centimeters or inches
>   either. The px unit is defined to be small but visible, and such that
>   a horizontal 1px wide line can be displayed with sharp edges (no
>   anti-aliasing). What is sharp, small and visible depends on the device
>   and the way it is used: do you hold it close to your eyes, like a
>   mobile phone, at arms length, like a computer monitor, or somewhere in
>   between, like an e-book reader? The px is thus not defined as a
>   constant length, but as something that depends on the type of device
>   and its typical use.